# Image Upload Not Retrieving "Orientation" exif data

Tags: image, upload, orientation, exif

I'm trying to fix an issue where when a portrait image is uploaded from a mobile, it doesn't save as the right orientation when it's opened on a desktop/browser.

I am using the code below to get the exif data to change it to the correct orientation but I am having issues:

```
$exif = exif_read_data($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 0, true);

Error: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0; array(4) {
      ["FILE"]=>
      array(6) {
        ["FileName"]=>
        string(11) "php18A7.tmp"
        ["FileDateTime"]=>
        int(1490020599)
        ["FileSize"]=>
        int(382988)
        ["FileType"]=>
        int(2)
        ["MimeType"]=>
        string(10) "image/jpeg"
        ["SectionsFound"]=>
        string(19) "ANY_TAG, IFD0, EXIF"
      }
      ["COMPUTED"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["html"]=>
        string(26) "width="2041" height="3628""
        ["Height"]=>
        int(3628)
        ["Width"]=>
        int(2041)
        ["IsColor"]=>
        int(1)
        ["ByteOrderMotorola"]=>
        int(1)
      }
      ["IFD0"]=>
      array(6) {
        ["ACDComment"]=>
        string(37) "Windows Photo Editor 10.0.10011.16384"
        ["Orientation"]=>
        int(8)
        ["Software"]=>
        string(37) "Windows Photo Editor 10.0.10011.16384"
        ["DateTime"]=>
        string(19) "2017:03:20 14:32:13"
        ["Exif_IFD_Pointer"]=>
        int(2242)
        ["UndefinedTag:0xEA1C"]=>
        string(2060) "�
        }
    }
```

The error shown above is a `var_dump($exif)` when an upload is done on a desktop browser. So as shown, it retrieves the "Orientation" data but when I do it on a mobile, it only retrieves the "FILE" array and the "COMPUTED" array and neither contains the "ORIENTATION" data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I realised that every time it got to the point where it tried to read the exif data using `exif_read_data()` the data was already gone.

I resulted to retrieving the exif data within the JavaScript instead using a library called [exif.js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js). Further explanation found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42921866/get-exif-data-on-upload-in-javascript).