# Can you get the exif data upon image upload using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, types, exif

I have an input file type:

```
<input type='file' id='upload_files' name='upload_files' file-model='upload_files'/>
```

I want to be able to extract the exif data if it exists from the uploaded image. Can this be done with javascript/angularjs alone?

I tried using `exif_read_data()` but it seems that by the time it reaches this point, the exif data has already been lost.

Comment: What is the question ? If it is *"Is what this library does possible ?"* then the answer is yes, it is possible (they do it). If it is *"Why **my** code is not working ?*", then we need to see it, it is really unlikely that your problem lies in this HTML markup. So if you could include and [MCVE], it would help us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

This is the solution that has worked for me. I used [exif-js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) JavaScript library to extract the exif data from an uploaded image if it exists.

**Further Use:**

I needed the exif data to get the original orientation of an image. I used the extraction of the exif data and I wrote the data into a file. I saved this file for later use and also use it to extract the Orientation value from the original state of the image. I use this value to appropriate rotate the final image.